# Is there a way to change mouse zooming to go left and right instead of up and down?

Tags: interface

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right mouse</kbd> zooming works by going up and down.

Is there any way to change this to left and right?

Comment: There are no standards in the industry for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can change the Zoom Axis to be horizontal instead.

[image]

Comment: Neato! Thanks! Don't know how I didn't spot that!